# Batch processing in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-processing

Rails query:

```
  Detail.created_at_gt(15.days.ago.to_datetime).find_each do |d|
      //Some code
  end
```

Equivalent mysql query:

```
  SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE (details.id >= 0) AND
                 (details.created_at > '2012-07-01 12:22:32')
                  ORDER BY details.id ASC LIMIT 1000
```

By using find_each in rails it is checking for details.id >= 0 and ordering details in
in ascending order.

Here, I want to avoid those two actions because in my case it is scanning whole table when
I have large data to process (i.e) indexing on created_at fails. So this is inefficient to do. Please anyone help.

Answer (score 2):

Here you've source of `find_in_batches` used in `find_each`:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

Click **Show source** link.
Essential lines are:

```
relation = relation.reorder(batch_order).limit(batch_size)
records = relation.where(table[primary_key].gteq(start)).all
```

and

```
records = relation.where(table[primary_key].gt(primary_key_offset)).to_a
```

You must order records by primary index or other unique index to process in batches and to select next batches. 
You can't do batches by `created_at` because it is not unique. But you could mix ordering by `created_at` and selecting by unique `id`:

```
relation = relation.reorder('created_at ASC, id ASC').limit(batch_size)
records = relation.where(table[primary_key].gteq(start)).all

#....

while records.any?
    records_size = records.size
    primary_key_offset = records.last.id
    created_at_key = records.last.created_at

    yield records

    break if records_size < batch_size

    if primary_key_offset
      records = relation.where('created_at>:ca OR (created_at=:ca AND id>:id)',:ca=>created_at_key,:id=>primary_key_offset).to_a
    else
      raise "Primary key not included in the custom select clause"
    end
end
```

If you are absolutely sure that no record, with the same `created_at` value, will be repeated more than `bach_size` times you could just use `created_at` as only key in batch processing.

Anyway you need index on `created_at` to be efficient.

Comment: I just want to index on created_at. Is it possible to define my own method?

Answer (score 0):

```
Detail.where('created_at > ? AND id < ?', 15.days.ago.to_datetime, 1000).order('details.id ASC')
```

You don't have to explicitly check `details.id >= 0` as Rails does it for you by default.

Answer (score 0):

Be better if you will use scopes and ARel style of quering:

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  table = self.arel_table

  scope :created_after, lambda { |date| where(table[:created_at].gt(date)).limit(1000) }
end
```

Than you can find 1000 records that was created after some date:

```
@details = Detail.created_after(15.days.ago.to_date_time)
```